# Python SQL cells interaction

Tags: python, database, rest, sqlite

I am using Python to try to gather the closing price for couple of different time intervals, save it in a database and then calculate the change in the closing price. This is my code:

```
def database_populate(symbol, interval):
    base_url = "https://www.binance.com/api/v1"
    url_klines = "/klines"
    end_time = requests.get('{}/time'.format(base_url)).json()['serverTime']
    start_time = end_time - 360000
    kln = requests.get('{a}{b}?symbol={c}&interval={d}&startTime={e}&endTime={f}'.format(a = base_url, b = url_klines, c = symbol, d = interval, e = start_time, f = end_time)).json()
    db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cr_db = """
        CREATE TABLE EOSBTC_symbol (
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        EPOCH_TIME INTEGER NOT NULL,
        CLOSE_PRICE FLOAT,
        CHANGE FLOAT )
    """
    cursor.execute(cr_db)

    for i in range(len(kln)):
        lst = [kln[i][0], kln[i][4]]
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO EOSBTC_symbol (EPOCH_TIME, CLOSE_PRICE) VALUES (?, ?)""", (lst[0], lst[1]))

    db.commit()
    db.close()


database_populate("EOSBTC", "1m")
```

This is populating the database with the closing price for a certain time period for the pair EOSBTC. I want to calculate the change in the closing price between two consecutive rows. Do I need to use the ID or the epoch time or there is another more elegant way? Just keep in mind that this DB will be continuously updated, so the ID and the EPOCH_TIME will change with time, and I want to calculate CHANGE field immediately after I populate these cells from the Binance API.

This is the database content at the moment:

[image: DB Content]

For example for in row 6 the CHANGE will be equal to 0.00082563 - 0.00082587, for row 5 0.00082587 - 0.00082533 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to calculate change in closing price in python and keep it only in python runtime, you should simply use a variable for previous row value.
2. If you want to store it in DB, you can have a small procedure that would do all the calculations and insert data including newly calculated difference.
3. If you want to retrieve value from DB every time, you might use something like TOP function, depending on RDBMS you are using.

Comment: can you suggest which of the proposed methods is the most efficient? I think 2) should be the best option, right?

Comment: Depends on the goal, how it will be used. If multiple consumers, than I would go with 2. Otherwise, 1 is the most efficient, with occasional runs of #3, if runtime was interrupted.

Comment: I want to add more columns to this row and eventually calculate the MACD lines, histogram, etc. and I want to keep them all in a DB, so that I can retrieve this information. It will poll the Binance website every minute for maybe 30-40 different crypto pairs and create similar databases for each combination. I need some algorithm which will consume the least amount of CPU cycles for this.

Comment: Yeah, 2nd option will suit you the best. Nice procedure will simplify implementation.